# font size changes after changing orientation in bootstrap based website

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

when I change my phone;s orientation to landscape and then again to portrait then the font size of "Welcome Student!" changes and instead of displaying it in two lines browser displays it in one line with smaller font size.I am using bootstrap 'display-1' for "Welcome" and 'display-3' for "Students!".I short the font size changes after returning to the original orientation.

```js
/* and if you want script also then */
function css_ruling() {
  var winw = window.innerWidth
  var winh = window.innerHeight
  var heading = document.getElementById("name")
  var first_look = document.getElementById("first")
  first_look.style.height = ((0.95) * winh) + "px";
  first_look.style.width = winw + "px";
}
setInterval(() => {
  css_ruling()
}, 5);
```

```css
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#first {
  background-image: linear-gradient(141deg, #9fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
}

#name {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}

.banner-img {
  background-image: url("../resources/banner.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 980px;
}

.avtar {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css?v=2">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=4">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="first">
    <div id="nav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Homework.com</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarColor01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info text-white my-2 my-sm-0 ml-auto mr-auto" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="name" class="pt-5"><span class="display-1">Welcome </span><span class="display-3">Students!</span></div>
    <div id="form_login">
      <form action="" class="">
        <div class="text-center pt-5">
          <img src="resources/man.svg" style="min-width: 90px" class="avtar" alt="">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="bootstrap/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="bootstrap/popper.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js?v=2"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using native API instead,

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  //styles
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  //styles
}
```

Using `setInterval` method to calculate device height and width not likely to give you desired result. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Critical_rendering_path

Comment: But I used `setInterval` method to resize the gradient background only so what is the relation of this with the font size